# Do complete graphs maximize the number of triangles?

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with $a\choose 2$ edges (and an arbitrary number of
vertices). Is it true that it has at most $a\choose 3$ triangles?

Context: this continues the question [Number of triangles in a graph based on number of edges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823481/number-of-triangles-in-a-graph-based-on-number-of-edges). As a matter of fact, someone
referred to this fact in his/her answers, but without a proof.

Comment: There should be a button at the bottom of your question marked "edit".  You could put the correction in.  At the same time, you could click the link icon at the top and make the linked question title into a link.  Thanks. I could do the first, but don't have the link.

Comment: Thank you, Ross (it is my first time here :-) ) -- all done.

Comment: Maybe this article here could helps. Take a look, in particular, to Theorem 4. It shows that the complete graphs maximize cycles of others sizes and a lot of other properties! =)

"Counting cycles and finite dimensional Lp norms" http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111106v1

Comment: Thank you very much, Rodrigo, that completely answers my question! (I think I know the author but I never knew he is working on these things :-) ) All the best, Alexander.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G(V,E)$ be a graph and let $T(G)$ be the number of triangles in $G$. The maximum number of triangles in $G$ would be when every choice of 3 vertices forms a triangle in $G$, so that would be when $G$ is complete and if $|V(G)|=n$ then $T(G)\le\binom{n}{3}$. On the other hand, the clique number of $G$, denoted $\omega(G)$, would give you a lower bound on the number of triangles $G$ could have because $\omega(G)$ is the order of the largest complete sub graph in $G$. Thus  $\binom{\omega(G)}{3}\le T(G)\le\binom{n}{3}$.